Finding all solutions for a Diophantine

If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers where $m^2+14m-32=3^n$, what is the
value of $m+n$? (MathCounts State 2022)

Since the RHS is a multiple of 3, the LHS must also be a multiple of 3.
Considering cases $\text{mod }3$ tells us that the number must be
$2 \text{mod }$
And checking values $m=2,5,8,11$ gives $m=11$ as the solution.
This works for this question since it says find the value, which implies there is only one solution. However, if that information had not been given (and this required writing a formal proof), how would you determine that this is the only possible solution?

$(m+16)(m-2) = m^2 + 14m - 32$

I know the factorization. How does it help me prove that there is only one solution?

what are two powers of $3$ that have difference $18?$

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that
$$m^2+14m-32=3^n.$$
The left hand side is a quadratic that we can easily factor over the integers to get
$$3^n=(m+16)(m-2),$$
and so by unique factorization of integers it follows that
$$m+16=u3^a\qquad\text{ and }\qquad m-2=v3^b,$$
for nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ with $a+b=n$, and units $u$ and $v$ such that $uv=1$. Of course over the integers that means $u=v=\pm1$. Also $m+16>0$ so $u=1$, and $m+16>m-2$ so $a>b$. Then $3^{a-b}$ is an integer and so again by unique factorization, the identity
$$3^b(3^{a-b}-1)=3^a-3^b=(m+16)-(m-2)=18=3^2\times2,$$
shows that $b=2$ and $a-b=1$, so $a=3$ and $n=a+b=5$. Then $m+16=27$ and $m-2=9$, yielding $m-11$ as the unique solution, and we find that $m+n=16$.

yeah, it wasn't clear whether the OP  could find all possible pairs of powers of 3  with difference 18.

For the question $m^2+14m-32=3^n$, it is said to be equivalent in asking the possible integer solution for the
$3^x=3^y+2$ where, $3^{x+2}=m+16$ and $3^{y+2}=m-2$.
As we already have $3^n-3^{n-1}\geq 2$ for all $n\geq 1$. Also, we can conclude that $3^k-3^j>2$ for all $k-j>1$. And so, the only possible value for which our original equation holds for integer values is at $(x,y)=(1,0)$, Which gives $m=11$ and $n= 5$, as the only integer solution for $m^2+14m-32=3^n$.

Why is $3^x=3^y + 2$?

@Starlight It's because after the factorisation,  we have the equation as form $(m+16)(m-2)=3^n$ which clearly states that to have the integer solution both $(m+16)$ and $(m-2)$ must have the form of $3^a$ and $3^b$ respectively. Now, after some rearrangement we get $3^{a-2} -3^{b-2}=2$. And this equation is just in the form $3^x=3^y+2$. In case to be especific equate $m+16=3^a$ and $m-2=3^b$ to get to the result.
